# Bounded String list to a listbox

Tags: c#

I am making a c# program with some **gui** components like `ComboBox` and `ListBoxes`. At the start of the program, i want to make one string list and bind it to a `listbox`. Now later in the program i copy a temp string list to my bounded string list. The problem is, the `ListBox` does not update the contents of the `ListBox`. Am i wrong in interpreting what a **datasource** binding does for `ListBoxes`? Why wont it work for me? Adding elements to the bounded string list works fine but copying another list onto the bounded list does not?

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

THanks

Comment: Please post code showing how you're binding the `ListBox`.

Comment: lstAllValFields.DataSource = fields  where fields is a List<string>

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), it will notify binding when it needs to update list.